# app cannot run after adding some listeners for three buttons

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I just started studying Androdid programming and have come up with some problems. I was trying to implement an app with a textview and three buttons(true_button, false_button, next_question). This project runs well on AVD. Later I added a prev_button and its listener for linking to the previous question. I also added a listener for the textview question_text_view. The Eclipse Indigo reported no error, but when running on an AVD, this program stops immediately after it is launched. Where is the problem? Or, how can I find the problems in programs when using such an IDE? Thank you.

Below are some of the programs for this project. (MainActivity.java, activity_main.xml, TrueFalse.java, strings.xml)

```
MainActivity.java
```

```java
package com.example1.geoquiz;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Button mTrueButton;
    private Button mFalseButton;
    private Button mNextButton;
    private TextView mQuestionTextView;
    private Button mNextButton2;
    private Button mPrevButton;

    private TrueFalse[] mQuestionBank = new TrueFalse[] {
            new TrueFalse(R.string.question2, true),
            new TrueFalse(R.string.question3, false),
            new TrueFalse(R.string.question4, false),
            new TrueFalse(R.string.question5, true),
            new TrueFalse(R.string.question6, true),
    };

    private int mCurrentIndex = 0;

    private void updateQuestion() {
        int question = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].getQuestion();
        mQuestionTextView.setText(question);
    }
    private void checkAnswer(boolean userPressedTrue) {
        boolean answerIsTrue = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].isTrueQuestion();
        int messageResId = 0;
        if(userPressedTrue == answerIsTrue) {
            messageResId = R.string.correct_toast;
        } else {
            messageResId = R.string.incorrect_toast;
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, messageResId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mQuestionTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.question_text_view);


        mTrueButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.true_button);
        mTrueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                checkAnswer(true);

            }
        });

        mFalseButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.false_button);
        mFalseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                checkAnswer(false);
            }
        });

        mNextButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.next_button);
        mNextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex + 1) % mQuestionBank.length;
                updateQuestion();
            }
        });

        /*Click the textview to get to next question.*/
        mNextButton2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.question_text_view);
        mNextButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex + 1) % mQuestionBank.length;
                updateQuestion();
            }
        });

        mPrevButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.prev_button);
        mPrevButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex - 1) % mQuestionBank.length;
                updateQuestion();

            }
        });
        updateQuestion();
    }

}




TrueFalse.java
```

```java
package com.example1.geoquiz;
public class TrueFalse {

    private int mQuestion;
    private boolean mTrueQuestion;
    public TrueFalse(int question, boolean trueQuestion) {
        mQuestion = question;
        mTrueQuestion = trueQuestion;
    }

    public int getQuestion() {
        return mQuestion;
    }
    public void setQuestion(int question) {
        mQuestion = question;
    }
    public boolean isTrueQuestion() {
        return mTrueQuestion;
    }
    public void setTrueQuestion(boolean trueQuestion) {
        mTrueQuestion = trueQuestion;
    }
}
```

```
MainActivity.xml
```

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/question_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/true_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
            android:text="@string/true_button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/false_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/true_button"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/true_button"
            android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
            android:text="@string/false_button" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/next_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/prev_button"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/prev_button"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
            android:text="@string/next_button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/prev_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="44dp"
            android:text="@string/prev_button" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>



strings.xml
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">GeoQuiz</string>
    <string name="question1">Shenzhen is near Hong Kong.</string>
    <string name="question2">The Pacific Ocean is larger than the Atlantic Ocean.</string>
    <string name="question3">The Suez Canal connects the Red Sea and the Indian Ocean.</string>
    <string name="question4">The source of the Nile River is in Egypt.</string>
    <string name="question5">The Amazon River is the longest river in the Americas.</string>
    <string name="question6">Lake Bakal is the world\'s oldest and deepest freshwater lake.</string>

    <string name="true_button">true</string>
    <string name="false_button">false</string>
    <string name="next_button">Next</string>
    <string name="prev_button">Prev</string>

    <string name="correct_toast">correct</string>
    <string name="incorrect_toast">incorrect</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: Debug your program. Check the logcat.

Comment: Is the mPrevButton the only thing added since the crash started? I see no issue that would cause that to crash at startup.  The proper method for debugging an Android app is using the ADB (Android Debug Bridge) program which is located in your SDK folder in the "platform-tools" folder.  I would expect you will find some sort of Nullpointer Exception which will lead you to the issue.

Comment: @aflatoon Yes it was fixed by following Zhak's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/*Click the textview to get to next question.*/
mNextButton2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.question_text_view);`
What did I just see?

`TextView` is not a button. If you're using `TextView`, you should cast to `TextView` in your code, not to `Button`; and set `android:clickable="true"` in your layout xml resource file